# Left join did not working properly in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to create a simple left join between two inputs (event hubs), the source of inputs is an app function that process a rabbitmq queue and send to a event hub.

In my eventhub1 I have this data:

```
[{
    "user": "user_aa_1"
}, {
    "user": "user_aa_2"
}, {
    "user": "user_aa_3"
}, {
    "user": "user_cc_1"
}]
```

In my eventhub2 I have this data:

```
[{
    "user": "user_bb_1"
}, {
    "user": "user_bb_2"
}, {
    "user": "user_bb_3
}, {
    "user": "user_cc_1"
}]
```

I use that sql to create my left join

```
select hub1.[user] h1,hub2.[user] h2 
into thirdTestDataset
from hub1 
    left join hub2 
        on hub2.[user] = hub1.[user]
        and datediff(hour,hub1,hub2) between 0 and 5
```

and test result looks ok...

[image: test result]

the problem is when I try it on job running... I got this result in power bi dataset...

[image: power bi result]

Any idea why my left isn't working like any sql query?

Comment: Hi, can you give me more info about your end-to-end flow? Do you output data to SQL then to PowerBI or directly to PowerBI?

Comment: event hub -> azure stream analytics -> power bi dataset.

basicly I send messages to event hub, try to join the inputs in stream and send the output to a power bi dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your query sql and it works well for me too.So when you can't get expected output after executing ASA job,i suggest you following troubleshoot solutions in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-output).

Based on your output,it seems that the `HUB2` becomes the left table.You could use [diagnostic log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-job-diagnostic-logs#send-diagnostics-to-azure-monitor-logs) in ASA to locate the truly output of job execution.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the end-to-end using blob storage for input 1 and 2 and your sample and a PowerBI dataset as output and observed the expected result.

I think there are few things that can go wrong with your query:

First, your join has a 5-hours windows: basically that means it looks at EH1 and EH2 for matches during that large window, so live results will be different from sample input for which you have only 1 row. Can you validate that you had no match during this 5-hour window?

Additionally by default PBI streaming datasets are "hybrid datasets" so it will accumulate results without a good way to know when the result was emitted since there is no timestamp in your output schema. So you can also view previous data here. I'd suggest few things here:

- In Power BI, change the option of your dataset: disable "Historic data analysis" to remove caching of data
- Add a timestamp column to make sure to identify when the data is generated (the first line of you query will become: select System.timestamp() as time, hub1.[user] h1,hub2.[user] h2 )

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks,

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)